# can Apache concurrent connection broke my app logic?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, server

Apache can handle up to 150 concurrent connections. is it possible to my app logic work wrong for this?

for example:
my app in one route check user's point then if user point is upper than 100 do some stuff and make user point zero

```
if($user->point>100){
//some stuff take one second
$user->point=0;
}
```

s
is it possible when doing stuff another request pass if statement?

UPDATE: i need more discuss on this question.
i do an experiment on Apache behavior:

```
$count=Count::find(1);

if($count->number<10){ //$count->number is 0 on database first;
    sleep(10);
    $count->number++;
    $count->save;
}
```

then i send 100 request concurrent to Apache, i think as Apache handle requests concurrent then $count->number can goes upper than 10 and reach 100

but it doesn't, why? and what happens if we have two servers with load balance? still will work correct? please provide information. thanks

UPDATE2: this experiment was wrong all of them get user at same time.. if we run correct experiment we face error.. for people who want read more about this problem they can search for **race condition**

Comment: Different requests won't interact with each other on that level. Each request in PHP starts from scratch, does it's thing and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Each Apache connection is handled with a different operation system process so memory access and such resources are safe. It is only the shared resources such as databases or files that might need attention.

As for Node server, it is a single process with same memory for all connections.

Comment: my question is about mysql. in this case i read points from mysql and do some stuff if user has more than x point and then make points=0 but is it possible to one user do this twice with one 100 point?

Comment: Yes it's possible unless you do locking or transactions.

Comment: it seems too dangerous